# Retrieving column values in filtered xpages view

Tags: xpages

I have a view defined on an xpage.  I also have several filters (based on the columns) that the user can select and combine to filter the results in the view.  I generate a query string based on this that I construct in dominoView.search (doing a complete refresh).  What I would like to do is get the results of the search so that I can then update some counts displayed elsewhere on the page.  I'm having a hard time figuring out where I can perform this logic, though.  I'm trying to use view.getAllEntries() and then iterating over the collection.  Sometimes it seems like it works, but other times I seem to be getting the unfiltered view.  Someone suggested I explicitly call view.FTSearch inside one of the events (beforePageLoad?) and immediately after do my getAllEntries call, saving the results in viewScope, but I get an "Error while browses Notes view" runtime error when I try to do that.  Any pointers?  TIA!

EDIT: After studying the xpages lifecycle a bit (which is still a little confusing), I think I can fine-tune my question.  This is my first stackoverflow question, so I hope this is okay to do and productive....

As I described, I have a dominoView defined on my xpage.  A repeat iterates over the rows of the view, displaying certain fields from the documents.  If I define a query in the search property, then the repeat correctly displays the reduced set of documents rather than the complete set.  (The query is computed in the search property via SSJS from some variables defined in the viewScope in a combobox's eventHandler.)  However, if I try to access the current entries in the view inside of the repeat's rendered section (with SSJS) using myView.getAllEntries (where myView is what's defined as the "value" of the repeat), I am still getting all of the documents, even if a query has been done.  It seems like at that point, the view variable has already had its search applied (since the repeat works), so why the differing results?  Is there another way to access the view's rows?  To complicate this further, this is just a simple experiment that might clarify the problem; as I indicated earlier, I don't actually want to access the view data within the repeat, I want to access it in the rendered or value sections of some comboboxes defined before the repeat in the xpage file.

I hope that makes more sense now....

EDIT #2: I forgot to add that if I manually call FTSearch (or FTSearchSorted) before calling myView.getAllEntries, then I think I can make this work.  It just seems unnecessary to have to do that in addition to the view's built-in search.

Comment: My original attempt involved calling view.getAllEntries() in javascript attached to the comboboxes that present the available filters to the user.  I'm actually iterating over the documents and retrieving the field values associated with that combobox filter, sorting them, and calculating the count of each valu which is put in parens. It's a lot like the faceted search you'd see at Amazon, for example.  If the user selects a second filter, I seem to be getting the entire unfiltered view, so it feels like I need to understand when the view's search is performed and insert my code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I get you want to iterate over the entries in a view that before has been filtered, i.e. whose resulting entry collection is smaller than the the view itself.

What I don't get (yet) is what you want to do with the result, or what you're axpecting to get from the iteration over your filtered view (you're mentioning some counts to be displayed somewhere else).

Probably a good way is to use the view's `.getAllEntriesByKey` method which returns a NotesViewEntryCollection object which then can be used for your iteration.

Don't forget to recycle the resulting NotesViewEntry objects; reason for this has been explained several times here at stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes, I want to iterate over the filtered entries.  The reason is that I have several potential filters defined on the left side (basically corresponding to columns in the view), and the user can select one or more of them to whittle down the results.  As filters are chosen, I want to update the counts of matches for the other available filters.  I hope that's clear.  The columns may not be sorted.  PS New to xpages, so I'm not clear on the page lifecycle and when a filtered view's contents are ready to be queried.  Thanks!

Comment: So you're thinking of some kind of drill-down filtering? This could become quite complicated with standard view filtering methods;  view.getAllEntries(), view.getAllEntriesByKey() and the like are actually doing the same stuff as their LotusScript equivalents. So if you're familiar with classic LS development then you should know what you can achive and how to handle the results.

Comment: I'm actually a fairly inexperienced classic Notes developer, too. My background is more in java, perl, C++, etc. It's a lot to pick up! In any case, thank you; as I mentioned in another comment, the main problem may be just not knowing when the search filter is applied to a view and when it's safe to get the view's entries.

Comment: One more detail (sorry if they're dribbling out): I'm building a query string for the view's search property based on what filters are selected (e.g. "([A] CONTAINS blah) AND ([B] CONTAINS foo)").  That part seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: ok, fulltext search then. You'll need to refresh that part of the page that contains the view datasource and its filtering definition.

Comment: FTSearch and FTSearchSorted both modify a view object that is sorted in original view order (ONLY if the database is not full-text indexed, otherwise, it is sorted by relevance). FTSearch modifies a view object using a single query, while FTSearchSorted allows you to use either a single query or a vector of queries. So, you could combine multiple queries by using FTSearchSorted.

Comment: I didn't realize FTSearchSorted allows for an array of queries, which are ANDed together.  That will simplify my query string, at least.  Thanks.